# How to read CSV file and create User

Tags: python-3.x, django, api

I want to read and create user from csv file. but my code gave me **MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/user/**
[image: I have pasted the image of result of the code]

## read and crate user from CSV file

my Code is:

```
def read_and_create_csv_file():
    header = {'Authorization': f'Token {get_token()}'}
    url = f"{URL}/api/user/"
    with open(r"E:\WC_API\employees.csv") as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            data = {
                "USERNAME": row['username'],
                "FIRST_NAME": row['FIRST_NAME'],
                "LAST_NAME": row['LAST_NAME'],
                "EMAIL": row["EMAIL"],
                "PASSWORD": "Abc@123"}

            response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=header)
        if response.status_code == 201:
            print("User created successfully")
        else:
            print("Failed to create user")


read_and_create_csv_file()
```

this is the resule:

```
Failed to create user or MultiValueDictKeyError
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the csv file, my guess is that there is not a column named 'username', and there is a column named 'USERNAME'. Change line #8 accordingly.

Comment: I have checked my CSV file there is no issue with column  'username'.

Comment: Print the contents of `row` before accessing values. What do you see?

Comment: It's working properly. I am able to see all content of row.